# How to show certain subgroups of $S_p$ are simple?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I met the following exercise: Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of $S_p$, where $p$ is a prime and the notion of transitive is defined in the usual sense (action on $\{1,2,...,p\}$). Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by elements of $G$ of order $p$. Prove: $H$ is a finite simple group.

So far, I only understood that since $G$ is transitive, its order is divided by $p$, so $G$ contains some $p$-cycles. Then what propositions can I use (I didn't see how to use Sylow) to attack this exercise? And by the way, I'm curious about whether there was any classification of simple subgroups of $S_p$ generated by $p$-cycles? Thanks a lot in advance for any hint or help!

Comment: I would look at a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ and see what I could say about its action.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I know that such a normal subgroup must be transitive since it’s nontrivial. But I didn’t find what I could do next?

Comment: So it's transitive on $p$ points, so its order is divisible by $p$ (the highest power of $p$ to divide $G$). OK now?

Comment: $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $p$-cycles. Now I see that normal subgroups of $G$ are all divided by $p$. But I’m sorry I still didn’t find the relations….(I’m a beginner, forgive my naïve questions if this is really trivial.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician ok, thanks. Now I completed the proof. Take a normal subgroup of $H$, say $N$, which is nontrivial. Since $H$ is transitive and $N$ is normal, $N$ is transitive. So the order of $N$ is divided by $p$. Then $N$ contains a $p$-cycle in $H$, which generates a Sylow-$p$ of $H$. Now by conjugacy of Sylow-$p$, $N$ contains all $p$-cycles in $H$, O.K.